# How to authenticate a post request in php

Tags: php, authentication, hmac, hmacsha1

I am trying to implement the HTTP Post Authentication, Which mentioned on this document https://www.clearslide.com/view/mail?iID=YS7LCS8XDPCABFR453DE , I am not able to understand what exactly i have to do to get this working, I tried to dump *$_REQUEST* and *$_SERVER* variables.

This is the output i am getting for this $_REQUEST

```
Array
(
    [emailpitchsent] =>
)
```

And this the output for $_SERVER

```
Array
(
    [HTTP_HMAC] => D4L1ICmRMii32PdCryBkpSNdxY5XDxC_OXsDTEucyzU
    [HTTP_DATE] => Thu, 12 Nov 2015 00:50:05 PST
    [HTTP_SHA1] => GTRFkX7JYVtDQgvrQeXJmHaCF24=
    [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 262
    [CONTENT_TYPE] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
    [HTTP_HOST] => myhost.com
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => Keep-Alive
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.7.0_55)
    [PATH] => /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => <address>Apache/2.2.31 (Amazon) Server at myhost.com Port 80</address>

    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.31 (Amazon)
    [SERVER_NAME] => myhost.com
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 0.0.0.0
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 0.0.0.1
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/vhosts/myhost.com/httpdocs
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => info@myhost.com
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/vhosts/myhost.com/httpdocs/clearslide.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 47400
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => POST
    [QUERY_STRING] => emailpitchsent
    [REQUEST_URI] => /clearslide.php?emailpitchsent
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /clearslide.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /clearslide.php
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1447318205
)
```

This i the content of clearslide.php

```
<?php
$req_dump = print_r($_REQUEST, TRUE);
$ser_dump = print_r($_SERVER,TRUE);
$fp = fopen('request.log', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $req_dump);
fwrite($fp, $ser_dump);
fclose($fp);
```

What i have to do now to get this thing working, How can i authenticate that request and get the data?.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the raw json body with `file_get_contents('php://input')` or `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`. Here is a sample of how to verify the signature from the headers. Also, here is a script that can generate a fake request for testing. Let me know if you have any more trouble. :)

**Verify the signature**

```
<?php
// https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/util/Base64#encodeBase64URLSafeString(byte[])
function urlsafe_b64encode($string) {
    $data = base64_encode($string);
    $data = str_replace(array('+','/', '='), array('-','_',''), $data);       
    return $data;
}

function extract_message(){
  $verb = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
  $sha1 = $_SERVER["HTTP_SHA1"];
  $content_type = $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];
  $request_time = $_SERVER["HTTP_DATE"];
  $path = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);     
  return "$verb\n$sha1\n$content_type\n$request_time\n$path";
}

function calculate_signature($to_sign, $api_key) {
  return urlsafe_b64encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $to_sign, $api_key, true));
}

function get_recieved_signature() { return $_SERVER["HTTP_HMAC"]; }

function verify_signature($recieved, $calculated) { return $recieved == $calculated; }

$api_key = "apikey";

$to_sign = extract_message();
$calculated_signature = calculate_signature($to_sign, $api_key);
$recieved_signature = get_recieved_signature();
$matched = verify_signature($recieved_signature, $calculated_signature);

$json_obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);

$fp = fopen('request.log', 'a');
fwrite($fp, print_r(array(
  '$_SERVER' => $_SERVER, 
  "JSON" => $json_obj,
  "SIGNATURE INFO" =>  array(
    "To Sign" => str_replace("\n", "\\n", $to_sign),
    "Received" => $recieved_signature,
    "Calculated" => $calculated_signature,
    "Matched" => $matched ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"
  )
), TRUE));
fclose($fp);
```

**Make a sample request**

```
<?php
// https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/util/Base64#encodeBase64URLSafe(byte[])
function urlsafe_b64encode($string) {
    $data = base64_encode($string);
    $data = str_replace(array('+','/','='), array('-','_',''), $data);
    return $data;
}

$sample_json = '{"company":"Example, Inc","pitchDetailsLink":"https://dev.clearslideng.com/manage/email/details?userVID=6YSZ9BBJWVM3H87PUAPE","senderEmail":"tester@clearslide.com","time":"Fri, 11/13/2015, 10:19 AM PST","recipients":["my@example.com"],"decks":["testing"]}';

$api_endpoint = 'http://localhost';

$verb = "POST";
$sha1 = base64_encode(sha1($sample_json));
$content_type = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
$request_time = date("D, d M Y H:i:s T");
$path = "/emailpitchsent";

$to_sign = "$verb\n$sha1\n$content_type\n$request_time\n$path";
$api_key = "apikey";
$signature = urlsafe_b64encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $to_sign, $api_key, true));

$ch = curl_init("$api_endpoint$path");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
 "CONTENT-TYPE: $content_type",
 "HMAC: $signature",
 "DATE: $request_time",
 "SHA1: $sha1"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sample_json);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo "To Sign: ". str_replace("\n", "\\n", $to_sign) ."\n\n";
echo "Response: \n\n$result";
```

**Example Log**

```
Array
(
    [$_SERVER] => Array
        (
            [USER] => vagrant
            [HOME] => /home/vagrant
            [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
            [QUERY_STRING] => event=emailpitchsent
            [REQUEST_METHOD] => POST
            [CONTENT_TYPE] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
            [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 270
            [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /vagrant/public/index.php
            [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
            [REQUEST_URI] => /index.php?event=emailpitchsent
            [DOCUMENT_URI] => /index.php
            [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /vagrant/public
            [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
            [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
            [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => nginx/1.1.19
            [REMOTE_ADDR] => 10.0.0.10
            [REMOTE_PORT] => 61094
            [SERVER_ADDR] => 10.0.0.200
            [SERVER_PORT] => 80
            [SERVER_NAME] => 192.168.22.10.xip.io
            [HTTPS] => off
            [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
            [LARA_ENV] => local
            [HTTP_HMAC] => vnQM9g41jE--rJvvwymezRY5VU9pf52Vu9sGhe_Gy-4
            [HTTP_DATE] => Thu, 19 Nov 2015 06:24:49 PST
            [HTTP_SHA1] => X7hjTy8DUzIUNO05JiuXp1DT3Js=
            [HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH] => 270
            [HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
            [HTTP_HOST] => 10.0.0.200
            [HTTP_CONNECTION] => Keep-Alive
            [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.7.0_91)
            [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
            [REQUEST_TIME] => 1447943089
        )

    [JSON] => Array
        (
            [company] => ClearSlide
            [pitchDetailsLink] => https://dev.clearslideng.com/manage/email/details?userVID=YGCD4WNJT377FQ6FTUFH
            [senderEmail] => tester@clearslide.com
            [time] => Thu, 11/19/2015, 6:24 AM PST
            [recipients] => Array
                (
                    [0] => test@example.com
                )

            [decks] => Array
                (
                    [0] => RockyBeach-720
                )

        )

    [SIGNATURE INFO] => Array
        (
            [Path] => /index.php
            [To Sign] => POST\nX7hjTy8DUzIUNO05JiuXp1DT3Js=\napplication/json; charset=UTF-8\nThu, 19 Nov 2015 06:24:49 PST\n/index.php
            [Received] => vnQM9g41jE--rJvvwymezRY5VU9pf52Vu9sGhe_Gy-4
            [Calculated] => vnQM9g41jE--rJvvwymezRY5VU9pf52Vu9sGhe_Gy-4
            [Matched] => TRUE
        )

)
```

**Example of Server Side toSign**

```
POST
X7hjTy8DUzIUNO05JiuXp1DT3Js=
application/json; charset=UTF-8
Thu, 19 Nov 2015 06:24:49 PST
/index.php
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
It works perfectly , And i am able to get the data, But i am not able to verify the data,

Comment: @Salim To confirm, you updated the value of `$api_key = "apikey";` to match what was set when configuring the notification endpoint?

Comment: Yes i did, And yea i can verify the data from local, but not from ClearSlide,   "urlsafe_b64encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $to_sign, $api_key, true));" , Are they using other variation of SHA instead on sha256, that's what i am thinking now.. Anyway thanks man,, :)

Comment: When configuring the notification endpoint, what did you specify as the URL? I'm guessing that the path part isn't matching.

Comment: The end url looks like this http://localhost/capture.php?event=, And i am getting the paths here in event parameter without any forward slash (/)(emailpitchsent), I tried to add slash(/) in front of path as well as without slash(/),

Comment: I added the output with my path set to the same as yours and the output from the server. All was good so I'm not sure what's happening here. Here is the vm I was using to test against the endpoint https://github.com/tjsingleton/cs-notification-php-example. Send me an email at [my first name]@clearslide.com and I can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Clearslide.com has free tech support for all of their users. You might want to try shooting them an email at support@clearslide.com - They'll be happy to assist with the setup.